# SwiftUI can't find SFSafariViewController in scope error

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiviewcontroller, supabase

I'm trying to implement social auth for google with SwiftUI in Supabase:

https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-swift#google-sign-in

The problem is with this part of the code in the tutorial:

```
import SafariServices

var safariVC: SFSafariViewController?
```

Getting the error:

```
Cannot find type 'SFSafariViewController' in scope
```

So I tried wrapping the above UIKit code:

```
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices

struct SafariView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    var url: URL
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SFSafariViewController {
        return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ safariViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: Context) {
        // Nothing to do here
    }
}
```

But getting the error:

```
Cannot find type 'UIViewControllerRepresentable' in scope
```

---

I've researched the issue against other questions, but can't get this to work. Can anyone help?

My development environment:

Xcode ver: 14.3.1

iOS deployment ver: 16.4

Comment: Does the same thing happen in a blank project?

Comment: I tested in a blank project and encountered the same error

Comment: Seems something is wrong with your Xcode in that case. Second example compiles fine for me

Comment: Thanks for the help, I played around with the default config and found the issue (added an answer to this question)

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by removing the macOS Supported Destinations that's added by default in latest Xcode.

Likely issue with lack of macOS support for UIView

Comment: Not just `UIView` -- `UIKit` in its entirety is not available on macOS (except via Catalyst)